# Coplanar Waveguide PCB Design for 2.4 GHz signal

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, iot

I tried to design a layout with 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi signal following coplanar waveguide. As far as I could understand from the online articles and videos, this is what I ended up with -

[image]

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=8ad6d9e5316247979470a1525af41e5d

But, I am not sure if this is the correct way or even I did the right thing. Using the calculators available, I am using these values:
[image]

So, I have two questions -

1. Is this even the right way to do this? If not, how should I do it?
2. If this is the right way, can the signal side ground plane be just ground tracks?

Comment: Coplanar means in the same plane. I am assuming that the red trace is on the top layer and the blue GND plane is on the bottom layer. A coplanar waveguide would put GND fill on the top layer with a space of W between edge of signal to edge of fill. You would use vias to stitch the fill to the bottom side GND plane.

Comment: Then, is it possible to use tracks as ground fill? Or just fill with gnd copper layer on top?

Comment: You could use tracks, I guess. Not sure how wide they would need to be to have the same effect as a plane. Probably a few multiples of S.

Comment: even if this was not coplanar, but microstrip over ground, your vias are not connected to the ground plane. Did you put them on the same net? And yes, you need your ground plane to be "clean" directly next to the trace, so what you've build has the opposite effect of what you wanted.

Comment: @mkeith then filling the top layer too should be better i think?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, that's one of the main reason, I asked, because the result didn't seem right to me.

Comment: Regardless of the coplanar waveguide, the layout is critically wrong for a 2.4GHz signal. Refer to the Espressif documents for guidance. Don’t try to guess this stuff.

Comment: There is an excellent article at https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Microwave_and_RF_Design_II_-_Transmission_Lines_(Steer)/03%3A_Planar_Transmission_Lines/3.08%3A_Co-Planar_Waveguide. The ground width should be >= 3s where s is the width of the signal track.

Comment: What's with all the vias next to the track with an uneven gap?